QGIS losing legend settings
I am consistently losing legend settings including font, spacing and size when I come back to a qgis project.
I am running QGIS 3.28, when I create a map and save and close it. If I come back to the same qgis project a few weeks later the settings are commonly lost and reset to the QGIS default.
I've not come across this issue after 5+ years using QGIS, could it be related to working with QGIS in sharepoint? Initially I thought it was to do with the installed custom font, but appears it looks potentially to occur when the QGIS project is downloaded from sharepoint?
Has anyone else had this issue or know how to keep the QGIS legend settings?

Do you use different versions of QGIS?

@katagena no, same versions. Only occurs with the legend, other text boxes and tables retain the correct font. Even when opening on other computers.
